# How to read data value for Cypress?

Tags: javascript, angular, cypress

I am trying to read data from API response.
The html in Chrome Inspect shows the value, but the number changes either to 4 or 5. I need Cypress to read the data, and based on the value, do a certain condition.

html

```
<p _ngcontent-wvl-c5="" class="availablelicenses"> 5 </p>
```

cypress

```
it("number of licences", function(){
    cy.get('p[class="availablelicenses"]').as("avc");
    cy.get('p[class="totallicenses"]').as("ls");
    if (avc == ls){
      cy.get('button[id="cyAdd"]').click()
      cy.get('p[class="add-user"]').contains('All licenses are already assigned')
    }
    else {
      cy.get('button[id="cyAdd"]').click()
      cy.get('[data-cy=cyFirst').type('testName')
      cy.get('[data-cy=cyLast').type('testLast')
      cy.get('[data-cy=cyEmail').type('testEmail@mailinator.com')
    }
  });
```

Comment: Not sure if it's possible in your scenario, but you should design the tests such that you know what the licence count will be, then create two tests one for 4 licences and another for 5 licences . Maybe you can stub the API with `cy.route()` to make each test see the appropriate number.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to get text first  like this:

```
const licensesOne = document.querySelector('p[class="availablelicenses"]').innerText;
const licensesTwo = document.querySelector('p[class="totallicenses"]').innerText;

if (licensesOne === licensesTwo) {
  // Checks to run if texts are equal
} else {
  // Checks to run if texts are different
}
```

Note that both `.innerText` & `.querySelector(…)` work only with one element at a a time. If you have more than one element, you might want to use a loop. Also, `.innerText` might work inconsistently across browsers.

Apart from that, as [@eric99](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8745435/eric99) correctly points out, `document.querySelector` will not wait at all for element to update/appear. So, if you run this test just after API call, you might prefer to use the method explained below.

There's also an alternative & slightly more involved way [proposed by Cypress](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-an-element%E2%80%99s-text-contents). Applied to your case, it would look something like this:

```
// Gets text of element and passes it to "then" callback
cy.get(`p[class="availablelicenses"]`).invoke('text').then(
  availableLicensesText => {
    //Gets text of second element & passes it to "then" callback
    cy.get(`p[class="totallicenses"]`).invoke(`text`).then(totalLicensesText => {
      if( availableLicensesText ===  totalLicensesText){
        // Checks to run if texts are equal
      } else {
        // Checks to run if texts are different
      }
    });
  }
);
```

Comment: The first line looks wrong - `cy.get()` returns a chainer, not an element like `document.querySelector()` does.  Did you test this code?

Comment: @eric99 I just did & you are right it returns a chainer. Thanks for pointing out, I've just updated the answer.

Comment: That looks good. Another thing, since the licence count is returned from an API `document.querySelector()` has no wait so the statement might run be the fetch completes. Cypress's `cy.get()` has a built-in wait, but will also return too quickly if `p[class="availablelicenses"]` is static (i.e on the Angular template prior to fetch). You might have more luck substituting `.should()` for `.then()` since should will apply timeouts to internal checks (your comment lines).

Comment: @eric99 Thank you, I updated the answer another time :)

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I recommend ditching the if statement, and performing two tests. This will give you better coverage by ensuring both paths are tested.

```js
context("number of licences", function() {

  it('when max licences not assigned, should allow licence entry', () => {

    cy.server();

    // Stubbed with mock response of same shape as real response
    cy.route('api/path/to/licence/count', {
      assigned: 4,   
      total: 5
    })

    cy.contains('p[class="availablelicenses"]', '4'); // confirms stubbed response used 
    cy.contains('p[class="totallicenses"]', '5');     

    cy.get('button[id="cyAdd"]').click()
    cy.get('[data-cy=cyFirst').type('testName')
    cy.get('[data-cy=cyLast').type('testLast')
    cy.get('[data-cy=cyEmail').type('testEmail@mailinator.com')
  });

  it('when max licences assigned, should not allow licence entry', () => {

    cy.server();

    // Stubbed with mock response of same shape as real response
    cy.route('api/path/to/licence/count', {
      assigned: 5,   
      total: 5
    })

    cy.contains('p[class="availablelicenses"]', '5'); // confirms stubbed response used 
    cy.contains('p[class="totallicenses"]', '5');     

    cy.get('button[id="cyAdd"]').click()
    cy.get('p[class="add-user"]').contains('All licenses are already assigned')
  });

});
```

---

If you can't stub the API, you could use something similar to Igor's last suggestion, but I would stay away from `document.querySelector('p[class="availablelicenses"]')` as it's going to be flakey, see this section of the docs [Retry-ability](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/retry-ability.html)
.

Also, use `should()` instead of `.then()` for the same reason.